# launchpad.net REST api for Java, code samples or experience

Tags: java, jersey, restful-architecture, jersey-client, launchpad

I am pretty new to java and REST, in an application  I am currently working on resources/tasks such as bug tracking are to be consumed from launchpad.net in a restful manner. There is an official python library (launchpadlib) that supports such interactions, but I want to do this using Java. I have looked around for samples to get me running to no avail. Does anyone have experience this in Java? Any insights is highly appreciated.

```
public class LaunchPad_Gatherer {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
  //WebTarget target = client.target("http://api.launchpad.net/1.0");
  //WebTarget target = client.target("https://api.launchpad.net/1.0/bugs/cve/2015-5223/bugs");
    WebTarget target = client.target("https://api.launchpad.net/1.0/bugs/cve");

    System.out.println(target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Sam many thanks. I have written a basic class to query some endpoints. There is very little documentation, maybe most people use python or other approaches...not sure. In my code (just edited initial question to added), I try different resource endpoints.